# On the convergence of isometries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, isometry-groups

**Proposition**: Let $(M,g)$ be a closed, compact Riemannian manifold. Let $f_n:M\to M$ be a sequence of isometries satisfying
$$
\|f_n - \iota\|_{L^2} \le \frac{1}{n},
$$
where $\iota:M\to M$ is the identity. Prove that there exists for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ a constant $c_n$, such that
$$
\|f_n - \iota\|_{C^k} \le \frac{c_k}{n},
$$
where the $C^k$-norm can be defined via local charts.
I.e., the $L^2$ convergence of isometries implies their $C^k$ convergence *at the same rate*.

This is not a surprising statement, given that it holds for Killing fields (because they form a finite-dimensional space).
I managed to prove this proposition, but I find the proof too complicated. Is there a simple argument?

Comment: Are you assuming that $M$ is closed and compact?

Comment: The following is a possible argument (dunno if it is simple after fully fleshed out): instead of looking at $f_n - \iota$ in charts, think about the vector field $v_n$ such that $f_n(x) = \exp_x(v_n(x))$. You basically want to prove that $\|v_n\|_{L^2} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ implies $\|v_n\|_{C^k} \leq \frac{c_k}{n}$, and this would be the case if you have elliptic regularity on $v_n$. But you do, since $v_n$ give rise to isometries, they give rise to harmonic maps.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, this is essentially the argument, but it is not so straightforward. I needed some kind og bootstrap before making this argument work. The $v_n$ being Killing fields, all norms are equivalent, so you don't even need to invoke ellpiticity,

Comment: Ah, then in that case I have no better ideas.